# How to "include" sound (e.g. wav file) in html?

Tags: html5-audio

I want to include the base64 version of a .wav file in html.

**SVG**

I have an .svg file called circ.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="792" height="612">  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow"></circle></svg>
```

I can embed it in my html file:

```
<html><body><embed src="circ.svg"></embed></body></html>
I can include it in my html file:
<html><body><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="792" height="612"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow"></circle></svg></body></html>
```

**PNG**

I also have .png file called htmlimg.png. I can embed it in my html file:

```
<html><body><embed src="htmlimg.png"></embed></body></html>
 I can convert it to based 64 and include the base64 version in my html file:
<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAO0AAABuC ... deleted stuff ... ASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/></body></html>
```

**WAV**

I also have a .wav file called Auld_Lang_Syne_-_U.S._Navy_Band.wav. I can embed it in my html file:

```
<html><body><audio controls><source src="Auld_Lang_Syne_-_U.S._Navy_Band.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio></body></html>
```

I can convert it to base64. Can I include the base64 version in html?

John

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

### Prefer external media file references

You can embed an audio file such as a .wav as an base64 encoded dataURL just like any other but you should probably don't do this.

Media files (audio and videos) are quite huge compared to image files (which are already quite "heavy" in filesize): easily above 1MB.

Embedding huge files as base64 encoded dataURLs will significantly bloat your page's document size and hence impact loading times.

More importantly, dataURLs have a [length limit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#length_limitations) in most browsers (albeit quite tolerant since the last years). So when working with larger files you should opt for external file references. They also provide better caching and asynchronous loading.

#### Audio compression

Keep also in mind that .wav is an uncompressed  audio format – it will require ~5–10 times more bytes than a compressed format like ogg, mp3 or aac.

Here's an example embedding a tiny (~36KB) mp3 – it already exceeded the SO snippet limit. It also makes your code quite ugly since you have to scroll around this huge base64 chunk =)

```js
/**
* fetch external mp3 and 
* convert it to base64 encoded dataURL
*/
(async()=>{
  let src = sampleAudio.src;
  let fetched = await fetch(src);
  let blob = await fetched.blob()
  let dataURL = await blobToBase64(blob);
  audiBase64.src=dataURL;
  textBase64.value=dataURL;
})()


/**
 * fetched blob to base64
 */
function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width:100%;
  min-height:10em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Audio example</h1>
<p><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio">See mdn docs</a></p>

<h2>External mp3</h2>
<audio id="sampleAudio" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3" controls></audio>

<h2>DataURL mp3 (base64 encoded)</h2>
<audio id="audiBase64" src="" controls></audio>

<textarea  id="textBase64" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

You can indeed convert pretty much any file to base64 passing it to a generic converter (or via simple JS methods) – it doesn't need to be a specific one for the current file type. You only need to prepend an appropriate mime prefix to the dataURl like e.g `data:audio/mpeg;base64,`, `data:audio/wav;base64,` etc. But it has a lot of drawbacks as explained.